# Error using Entity Enhancement with Eclipse, openJPA, Tomcat and OracleDB

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, openjpa

I developed a few JSF/JPA applications with Eclipse Link, Glassfish and OracleDB. My new topic ist porting an application to Tomcat with openJPA. So I am testing a little, easy application with this new technology. This is more difficult as I thought. I learned from here:

http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-eclipse.html

that I have to enhance my Entities.  I tried with the Eclipse Plugin which in part was succesfull but had few problems. In a few posts I saw that it is recommended using the Ant method, which I am currently trying.  I made the same configuration as mentioned in the link, but I get a bad error and I don't know whats the problem:

> C:\Users\XXX\EclipseWorkspace\testJSF\enhance.xml:26:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: MetaDataFactory could not
>   be configured (conf.newMetaDataFactoryInstance() returned null). This
>   might mean that no configuration properties were found. Ensure that
>   you have a META-INF/persistence.xml file, that it is available in your
>   classpath, or that the properties file you are using for configuration
>   is available. If you are using Ant, please see the  or
>    attributes of the task's nested  element.
>   This can also occur if your OpenJPA distribution jars are corrupt, or
>   if your security policy is overly strict.

My enhance.xml

```
<path id="enhance.cp">
    <pathelement location="${basedir}${file.separator}${build.dir}"/>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}${file.separator}${openjpa.libs}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
</path>

<property name="cp" refid="enhance.cp"/>

<target name="openjpa.libs.check" unless="openjpa.libs">
    <fail message="Please set -Dopenjpa.libs in your builder configuration!" />
</target>

<target name="build.dir.check" unless="build.dir">
    <fail message="Please set -Dbuild.dir in your builder configuration!" />
</target>

<target name="enhance" depends="openjpa.libs.check, build.dir.check">
    <echo message="${cp}"/>
    <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask">
        <classpath refid="enhance.cp"/>
    </taskdef>
    <openjpac>
        <classpath refid="enhance.cp"/>
    </openjpac>
</target>
```

I don't believe that persistence.xml cannot be found, because when I use the Eclipse Plugin, I am able to extract Data from the Database. But then I get this error:

> The Entity "openJPA.Todo_" was enhanced at level "2", but the current
>   level of enhancement is "1.241.207".

I don't understand what this means. I am getting very frustraded. How can I get a working project with Eclipse, Tomcat and OpenJpa?

Thank you in advance

Steve

**UPDATE**

Here I found a tutorial that says to copy the persistence.xml into the build folder:
http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-ant.html
I copied the META-INF Folder with the persistence.xml in the build folder and now the described error is gone.

But the enhancer doesn't find my persistent class:

```
enhance:
        [echo] C:\Users\XXX\EclipseWorkspace\testJSF\build;C:\Users\XXX\EclipseWorkspace\testJSF\lib\openjpa-all-2.2.0.jar
    [openjpac] 12  TODO  TRACE  [Worker-119] openjpa.Runtime - Setting the following properties from "file:/C:/Users/XXX/EclipseWorkspace/testJSF/build/META-INF/persistence.xml" into configuration: {openjpa.ConnectionPassword=XXX, openjpa.ConnectionDriverName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, openjpa.MetaDataFactory=jpa(Types=openJPA.Todo_), openjpa.Log=DefaultLevel=TRACE, PersistenceVersion=2.0, openjpa.ConnectionUserName=XXX, openjpa.ConnectionURL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:TEST, openjpa.Id=TODO}
    [openjpac] 29  TODO  TRACE  [Worker-119] openjpa.Runtime - No cache marshaller found for id org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataCacheMaintenance.
    [openjpac] 454  TODO  TRACE  [Worker-119] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning resource "META-INF/orm.xml" for persistent types.
    [openjpac] 461  TODO  TRACE  [Worker-119] openjpa.MetaData - The persistent unit root url is "null"
    [openjpac] 461  TODO  TRACE  [Worker-119] openjpa.MetaData - parsePersistentTypeNames() found [openJPA.Todo_].
    [openjpac] 461  TODO  TRACE  [Worker-119] openjpa.MetaData - Found 1 classes with metadata in 19 milliseconds.
    [openjpac] 472  TODO  INFO   [Worker-119] openjpa.Tool - Enhancer running on type "openJPA.Todo_".
    [openjpac] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: openJPA.Todo_
```

And the search goes on!

Comment: The warning message "he Entity "openJPA.Todo_" was enhanced at level "2"" means that your Entities have already been enhanced by an older version of the enhancer than what is currently running. Have you made certain that C:\Users\XXX\EclipseWorkspace\testJSF\build\openjpa.Todo_.class exists?